# SQL Server rank query optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization, ranking

I'm trying to optimize a query to get the rank of a user in specific country from the DB. Currently is seems very inefficient.

I'm trying to determine what can be done to improve it.

*This is the current SQL:*

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM leaderboard lb, users u
WHERE u.country = 'United States' 
  AND lb.id = u.id 
  AND lb.score + 1 > (SELECT lb2.score 
                      FROM leaderboard lb2
                      WHERE lb2.id = some_user_id);
```

*Details:*

`Users` table:

- `id` is the primary key
- `country` column is indexed

`Leadeboard` table:

- `id` is the primary key
- `score` column is indexed

[image]

*The execution plan shows 2 warnings:*

> Columns With No Statistics: [dbo].[leaderboard].id (cost 23%)
>
> Columns With No Statistics: [dbo].[users].id (cost 28%)

Comment: Could you post some DDL, Sample data and Expected result please?

Comment: Execution plan would help a lot on this too. And where's the rank function?

Comment: Why you don't use `RANK()OVER(...)`?

Comment: This query is based on a query I already use and which works very good, 
   SELECT @p_rank = COUNT(*) + 1
    FROM leaderboard lb
    WHERE ur.score > (SELECT ur2.score FROM leaderboard lb2 
   WHERE ur2.id = some_id);
I had to add a join for the country column.

Comment: What is `some_user_id`, why you need this filter on the third table? I don't know why you need this table `q360_leaderboard` at all.

Comment: I'm trying to get the rank of a specific user

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, it's leaderboard table. I've edited the question.

Comment: Don't use old style joins

Comment: If you share the execution plan we might be able to help with the missing statistics, which can resolve this issue.

Comment: @artm I've added a screenshot of the execution plan.

Comment: What's the output for `select
    tblSS.name     
    , tblSS.auto_created 
    , tblSS.user_created
    , [index] = tblSI.name        
from   sys.stats tblSS
    left outer join sys.indexes tblSI
      on  tblSS.object_id = tblSI.object_id
      and tblSS.stats_id = tblSI.index_id
where  tblSS.object_id 
      = object_id('dbo.leaderboard')`

Comment: PK_leaderboard                 0 0 PK_leaderboard
nci_wi_leaderboard_score 0 0 nci_wi_leaderboard_score
nci_wi_leaderboard_daily 0 0 nci_wi_leaderboard_daily
nci_wi_leaderboard_weekly 0 0 nci_wi_leaderboard_weekly

Let me know if it's not readable and I will add a screen shot in the question.

Comment: Statitics are not auto created then. Can you try (at your own risk) creating these statistics and see if the query time improves? `CREATE STATISTICS [stat_leaderboard_id]
    ON dbo.leaderboard
    (
          Id
    )
    WITH FULLSCAN;


    CREATE STATISTICS [stat_users_id]
    ON dbo.users
    (
          Id
    )
    WITH FULLSCAN;`

Comment: If you have a developer/test environment try there first. Or backup/restore the database on the test server and try on the backup before production. SQL should create the statistics when it deems necesarry but if they haven't been auto-created, creating them manually shouldn't cause any problems but if the tables are large and creating them will be using tempDb, it might slow down the server. After creating the statistics and it fixes the issue, you'll probably also need to look at why they are not auto-created.

Comment: Two suggestions: (1) Create a _single_ index on `users` composed of `country` and `id` and one on `leaderboard` composed of `id` and `score`. (b) Change the `score` comparison so that you aren't performing arithmetic on the column, i.e. `... and lb.score >= ( select ... )` or `... and lb.score > ( select ... ) - 1`. (I'm assuming that `score` is an integer.)

Comment: What if the `Some_User_id` does not belong to a user of the `'United States'` ... this query contains logical errors

Comment: @Yahfoufi - you are correct, but please assume that there will be a correlation between the user and country

Comment: the sql statement you use in the question fails the logic. Here is an example with five users, the user with the id 1 has 75 points and should be on 3rd rank while your query results in ranking him on rank 5. Check this: http://rextester.com/YSKBO82261

Comment: @RaulSebastian I don't think it's because of the logic problem, but because of the count(*) + 1

Comment: @UdiIdan it is not the `count(*) + 1`, it is the `score + 1` and that is a problem of implementation logic.

Comment: Did using [covering indexes](http://www.dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup/) make a difference in performance? ("Create a _single_ index on `users` composed of `country` and `id` and one on `leaderboard` composed of `id` and `score`.") Note that SQL Server 2005 and later versions support [included columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190806.aspx) as well as composite indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update 1: Just remove computation from where clause and use Joins

*Based on your comments, if my first suggestion didn't improve the performance then i think the only thing you can do is: **first of all, make sure that you created all needed indexes and statistics** and **remove computation from the `WHERE` clause**, because it is not necessary, and **use JOINs** instead of linking table in the where clause (Using Joins doesn't improve performance but it's [syntax is clearer and less ambiguous](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/what-is-more-efficient-a-where-clause-or-a-join-with-million-plus-row-tables))*

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM leaderboard lb INNER JOIN users u
ON lb.id = u.id 
WHERE u.country = 'United States' 
AND lb.score  > (SELECT lb2.score 
                  FROM leaderboard lb2
                  WHERE lb2.id = some_user_id)
```

*Note that `lb.score  + 1> (SELECT lb2.score FROM leaderboard lb2 WHERE lb2.id = some_user_id)` is equivalent to `lb.score  >= (SELECT lb2.score FROM leaderboard lb2 WHERE lb2.id = some_user_id)` if score is integer, and you don't need it.*

---

## Initial answer: Use one of the Ranking functions with a subquery or CTE

I think it is better to use a ranking function like `RANK()`

**Subquery**

```
SELECT * FROM (

    SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.country, lb.score, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY lb.score DESC) AS rnk
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN leaderboard lb ON u.id = lb.id
    WHERE u.country = 'United States' 

) T1 WHERE T1.user_id = some_user_id
```

**Common table expression**

```
 WITH CTE_1 AS (

    SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.country, lb.score, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY lb.score DESC) AS rnk
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN leaderboard lb ON u.id = lb.id
    WHERE u.country = 'United States' 

) SELECT * FROM CTE_1 WHERE CTE_1.user_id = some_user_id
```

**References**

- [Ranking Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ranking-functions-transact-sql)
- [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql)
- [Subquery Fundamentals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: I've tried both options, but they are much slower than the original.

Comment: This one works much better than the previous. It's now about the same as the original query, Maybe it's the best possible.

Comment: @UdiIdan i agree with that

Comment: @UdiIdan i think that the only way you can optimize the query is to create the necessary indexes and statistics, if so then you are on the right way

Comment: I did. I also tried a totally different approach, which can be seen here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287218/stored-procedure-slow-when-executed-from-application-server?noredirect=1#comment83564958_48287218

Comment: I think that this is the only suitable answer (the answer update part), it enhance the performance a very little bit, but this is the only way, the query is already good

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for something like:

```
SELECT u.id AS user_id, u.country, lu.score, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY lu.score DESC) AS rnk
FROM users u
INNER JOIN leaderboard lu ON u.id = lu.id
WHERE u.country = 'United States'
```

You can see a demo here: http://rextester.com/KHM76159

Comment: Thanks, but it seems this query will return the rank as 1 no matter who is the user.

Comment: @UdiIdan you are using it wrong then. See http://rextester.com/QWP15044

Comment: You are correct, it does work. Unfortunately it's slower than the original query.

Comment: This is the correct response and should be marked as such. I checked the query plan and it outperforms your initial statement. I will post a link

Comment: @RaulSebastian - although you might be correct in theory, I did check this query on the server. Unfortunately it's much slower than the original (3X CPU time and 4X elapsed time).

Comment: This query will return all users ranking from all countries, it is not an optimization of the OP query!!

Comment: Then there is no need to `PARTITION BY country`

Comment: Ok edit approved. Once you specify country below, the partition is not needed

Comment: @UdiIdan here is kbball query constrainted to a single userId compared with your original statement, with the schema as described in your question: http://rextester.com/PCP89821
I have tested it on Sql Server 2008R2, 2012 and 2016 all enterprise. It performs more than 20% faster from perspective of reads, cputime and the query plan is compact.

Answer (score 2):

Try storing the `score` in a variable then use it within the `JOIN` clause.

```
declare @score int = ( select top 1 score 
                       FROM leaderboard
                       WHERE id = some_user_id 
                     );

SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 as 'rank'
FROM leaderboard lb
JOIN users u
  ON lb.id = u.id 
 AND lb.score > @score
 AND u.country = 'United States';
```

Comment: After testing this approach, no performance improvement made at all

Comment: @Yahfoufi It was worth a try

Answer (score 0):

Make it more readable/testable and force execution steps using CTE's

```
WITH scoreToRank AS (
  SELECT score
  FROM leaderboard
  WHERE id = {some_user_id}
)

, usersInCountry AS (
  SELECT id
  FROM users
  WHERE country = 'United States'
)

, countOfUsersWithGreaterScore AS (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM leaderboard l
  INNER JOIN usersInCountry u ON u.id = l.id
  WHERE l.score > (SELECT score FROM scoreToRank)
)

SELECT count + 1 AS usersRank FROM countOfUsersWithGreaterScore
```

Depending on SQL version and data density, using as IN clause for countOfUsersWithGreaterScore / usersInCountry may be more efficient

Comment: *and force execution steps using CTE*: This is wrong... CTEs are very readable, but they are not executed in the order you see. Go [to this connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=218968) and vote for it. And [read this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/82c97fa4-2b63-4d0d-90c6-56943fcecd29/cte-execution-order?forum=sqldatabaseengine)

Comment: @Shnugo I don't normally use SQL Server, and this code would work on most modern SQL engines. I tested this on SQL Server 2016 and the execution plans followed the steps as per CTE layout. Maybe with simpler queries SQL Server tries to optimise them out, but in this case not so much

Comment: However - this is random... A CTE **does not influence the order of execution in any way** (regretfully!). It's the engine chosing the - hopefully - best way. That's why some processes run much faster if you push the CTE's result into a temp table instead. But this cannot work in `VIEWs` or `iTVFs`. Please vote the connect issue and let's hope for a future version.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?  It looks a little odd but I think it might work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM leaderboard lb, users u, leaderboard lb2
WHERE u.country = 'United States' 
  AND lb.id = u.id 
  AND lb.score + 1 > lb2.score AND lb2.id = some_user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer joins over subqueries, the query below should give you the same result from your question.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM leaderboard lb2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.Id <> lb2.Id AND u.country = 'United States'
    LEFT OUTER JOIN leaderboard lb ON lb.Id = u.Id
WHERE lb2.Id = some_user_id AND lb.score >= lb2.score
```

If some users don't have scores than you should check for null values or you could change the joining order, which might even be better in some cases:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
FROM leaderboard lb2
    LEFT OUTER JOIN leaderboard lb ON lb.Id <> lb2.Id AND lb.score >= lb2.score 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON u.Id = lb.Id
WHERE lb2.Id = some_user_id AND u.country = 'United States'
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your query, but rather the overall problem in case that's useful.

I confronted the same for an international contest where the teams table could get quite big. I never was able to get an SQL ranking query to perform well enough for a good user experience (goal was 80ms, and the query was somewhat more complex than yours), so finally decided to use a [redis server](https://redis.io/) just for returning ranks.

It provides a ranking function exactly suited to this problem. It's fast: a few millis for a table of 10 million contestants.

I still regarded scores stored in the SQL DB as the source of truth. Redis isn't ACID. It saves to disk only snapshots of its data image in RAM. If the server goes down, it reverts to the last snapshot. So redis and the source of truth could diverge a bit.

This wasn't any problem in my case because instantly returned ranks were acknowledged to be unofficial pending final review by judges. Missing data due to reboots from snapshot were "self healing". That is, if I queried for the rank of a team and it wasn't in the redis store, I added it then re-queried. I also ran a daily sync job to restore perfect agreement. I could run this sync at any time to initialize a new redis from scratch.

This scheme proved extremely fast and robust for 7 years. The implementation it replaced used a custom BerkeleyDB-based service. That one worked well for the preceding 7 years.

One other point is that a redis service can be very handy for other purposes like caches.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try denormalizing? For each row in the leaderboard table, include the user's country.

Also, use a CountryID instead of the country name, since ints are faster to query than varchar. (You can look up the name for the country separately.)

Then you could get the count you're seeking without needing a join or subselect - it would just be a select on a single table (and a faster one, since you would be using an int).

Comment: Note: For country a tinyint should be big enough.

Answer (score -1):

try something like :

```
SELECT score FROM leaderboard WHERE id in
    SELECT id FROM users WHERE country='United States' and id=some_user_id
```